# Fazendo um atualização com relacionamento usando REST,Jax-rs,Jersey e Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, restful, jersey, jax-rs

Bem, peguei uma base para fazer um CRUD simples de apenas uma tabela usando REST e os demais que coloquei na questão, tudo funcionou perfeitamente, até eu colocar mais tabelas(classes) e relacionamento entre elas, apos o acréscimo dos relacionamentos ainda consigo vizualizar a informação e até mesmo excluir, mas não consigo fazer uma atualização ja tentei diversas coisas e nada, em uma das minhas ultimas tentativas tentei fazer algo similar a o que eu fiz no java em uma classe que criei para testar minhas DAO's ,  gostaria muito de saber os motivos de tal problema  ficarei muito grato pelo auxilio.
  Informações extras, Ordem de servico tem relacionamento com cliente,serviço e status ja o cliente tem relacionamento com usuario e nivel.

**Codigo java da classe Main test que criei para testar as Classes DAO (JAVA):**

```
//UPDATE ORDEM DE SERVICO.
        ServicoDAO sdao = new ServicoDAO();
        Servico serv = sdao.porId(2);

        UsuarioDAO udao = new UsuarioDAO();
        Usuario usu = udao.porId(4);

        NivelDAO niDAO = new NivelDAO();
        Nivel niv = niDAO.porId(2);

        ClienteDAO cliDAO = new ClienteDAO();
        Cliente cli = cliDAO.porId(3);
        cli.setNivel(niv);
        cli.setUsuario(usu);

        OrdemDeServicoDAO dao = new OrdemDeServicoDAO();
        OrdemDeServico ordem = new OrdemDeServico(2);
        ordem.setStatus(2);
        ordem.setCodServico(serv);
        ordem.setCodCliente(cli);

        dao.atualizar(ordem);
        System.out.println(" " + ordem.getStatus());
```

**Codigo da Resource(Apenas o que achei necessario mostrar)(JAVA):**

```
@Path("/ordens")

public class OrdemDeServicoResource {
OrdemDeServicoDAO dao = new OrdemDeServicoDAO();

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public OrdemDeServico atualizar(OrdemDeServico ordem)throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Atualização de ordem de servico:" +ordem.getStatus());
    dao.atualizar(ordem);
    return ordem;
}

@DELETE @Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void remover(@PathParam("id")int id)throws Exception{
    OrdemDeServico ordem = dao.porId(id);
    dao.delete(ordem);

}
```

**Codigo Javascript OrdemDetalhes:**

```
var rootURL ="http://localhost:8080/TCC02/rest";

var rootcli = "http://localhost:8080/TCC02/rest/clientes/";

var rootser = "http://localhost:8080/TCC02/rest/servicos/";

var rootLogin ="http://localhost:8080/TCC02/rest/usuarios/"

listOrdem();

function listOrdem(){
    var id = getId();
    $("#orId").attr("data-value",id);
    if(id<1){
        alert('id invalido');
        return;
    }
    console.log('getOrdem ' +id);
    $.getJSON(rootURL + '/ordens/' + id, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Ordem de servico não encontrada');
            return
        }
    var ordem = data;
    renderDetails(ordem);
    return ordem;       
    });
}

function porIdSer(id3){
    console.log('Ache o Servico pelo ID: ' +id3);
    $.getJSON(rootser + id3, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Cliente não encontrado por id');
            return
        }
        var ser = data;
        renderDetailsSer(ser);
        return ser;
    });
}

function porIdLogin(id4){
    console.log('Ache o Usuario pelo ID: ' +id4);
    $.getJSON(rootLogin + id4, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Usuario não encontrado pelo id');
            return
        }
        var usu = data;
        renderDetailsUsu(usu);
        return usu;
    });
}

function porIdNivel(id5){
    console.log('Ache o nivel pelo ID: ' + id5);
    $.getJSON(rootURL+ '/niveis/'+ id5,function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Id do nivel não compativel');
            return
        }
        var niv = data;
        renderDetailsNiv(niv);
        return niv;
    });
}

function porIdCli(id2){
    console.log('Ache Cliente Pelo iD:' + id2);
    $.getJSON(rootcli + id2, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Cliente não encontrado por id');
            return
        }
        var cli = data;
        renderDetailsCli(cli);
        return cli;
    });
}

    $('#btnAtt').click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
        console.log('Carregar Detalhes');
        var id = getId();
        if(id<1){
            alert ('id invalido');
            return;
        }
        console.log ('getOrdem' + id);
        $.getJSON(rootURL+'/ordens/' + id, function(data){
            if(!data){
                alert('Erro ao selecionar o id');
                return
            }
            var ordem = data;
            renderDetails1(ordem);
        });
    });

    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        atualizarOrdem();
    });

    function atualizarOrdem(){
        var ident = $("#orId").attr("data-value");
        console.log('Atualizar Ordem de servico:' +ident);
        $.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url:rootURL + '/ordens/' + ident,
            dataType:"json",
            data:formToJSON(),
            success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                alert('Ordem de serviço atualizada com sucesso');   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Erro ao atualizar a ordem de servico ' + errorThrown);           
            }
        });
    }

    function deletarOrdem(){
        console.log('Deletar ordem de serviço');
        $.ajax({
            type:'DELETE',
            url:rootURL + '/' + $('#orId').val(),
            success: function(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert('Ordem de serviço deletada'); 
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Erro ao deletar ordem de serviço')
            }       
        });
    }
function getId(){
    //localiza e pega o id da url
    var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    //Confirmar se o ID é um int
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    return intRegex.test(id)? id : -1;
}
// Pega os dados em JSON e arruma eles na minha form.
function renderDetails(ordem){
    $('#orId').val(ordem.id);
    $('#nomecliente').val(ordem.codCliente.nome);
    $('#servico').val(ordem.codServico.nomeservico);
    $('#codserv').val(ordem.codServico.id);
    $('#codcli').val(ordem.codCliente.id);
    $('#status').append('<option>' + ordem.status + '</option>');   
    //Definindo valores para campos codservico e codcliente de acordo com seu relacionamento com OrdemServico.
    var atributo2 = ordem.codServico.id;
    $("#codserv").attr("data-value",atributo2);
    var atributo = ordem.codCliente.nivel.id
    $("#codcli").attr("data-value",atributo);   
    porIdCli(atributo);
    porIdSer(atributo2);
}

function formToJSON(){
    var orId = $('#orId1').val();
    return JSON.stringify({
        "id": orId == "" ? null : orId,
        "status": $('#status1').val(),
        "servico": $('#servico1').data(),
        "nomecliente":$('#nomecliente1').data(),        
    });
}
```

Comment: No código que atualiza a ordem, na linha   dao.atualizar(ordem); , ao invés de mandar atualizar direto, tenta localizar essa ordem antes e depois manda atualizar ela. Já tive problemas com JPA que resolvi assim, achando antes o objeto e mandando atualizar pelo objeto achado. Talvez se você fizer isso resolva. Tenta aí.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o que acontece é que eu faço exatamente isso só que do lado do cliente na minha função **atualizarOrdem()** no javascript eu seleciono a OrdemDeServico especifica pelo seu Id, como comentei consigo fazer a atualização com minha classe main em java, mas não consigo fazer a atualização do lado cliente ou seja pela função em javascript esse que esta sendo o meu problema.

Comment: Então, ainda estou parado nessa parte e não achei nenhuma solução ainda, alguem consegue encontrar alguma luz para esse problema?

Comment: Quando executa sua função  atualizarOrdem() do javascript,  o retorno mostra o seu alert do success ou o do error? Se for o do error,  qual o erro que aparece?  Se for o do success,  o que você gostaria que acontecesse a mais? O retorno do Java está na variável data.

Comment: Mostra o do error, mas aparece apenas a mensagem sem muitas informações como um codigo de erro por exemplo o 500, no caso vi no log qual URL estava sendo passada e foi essa que estava sendo passada quando eu executava a função: **localhost:8080/TCC02/GerenteArea/servico/ordemDetalhes.html?orId1=2&servico1=%5Bobject+Object%5D&nomecliente1=%5Bobject+Object%5D&status1=1#2**  Nesse caso expecifico só quero atualizar o Status nesse caso era 1 e tentei mudar para 2.

Comment: Se for possivel, gostaria de criar algo igual o da minha classe java de teste só que no javascript ja tentei de tudo que consegui pensar mas nada funcionou provavelmente por que preciso usar essas URL's.

Comment: Na documentação ajax do Jquery tá escrito o seguinte:

error - 
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". (continua)

Comment: (continuação) When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event. Fonte: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Isto para mim significa que a página que está sendo chamada com Ajax está retornando erro 500 (Internal Server Error). Tente ver se ao ser processada sem ser por requisição ajax(se vc puder acessar a página diretamente, ou criar um teste passando os mesmos dados que o ajax passa mas sem ser por ajax) se a página tb dará esse erro e se der, será mais fácil de debugar sem ficar passando pelo ajax. Para mim o seu ajax está normal e tem que ver porque o Java está dando erro. Verifique se está passando os parâmetros via ajax corretamente tb depois.

Comment: Entendo ficaria realmente melhor para ver os erros mas poderia me dar um exemplo do que eu poderia utilzar em vez de ajax? .

Comment: Outra coisa, estava vendo aqui que a URL que eu mandei estava meio errada arrumando obtive essa URL onde faz mais sentido pratico para a aplicação agora quando clico em atualizar esse link que aparece; **localhost:8080/TCC02/GerenteArea/servico/ordemDetalhes.html?servico=%5Bobject+Object%5D&codserv=2&nomecliente=%5Bobject+Object%5D&status=2** , não sei se ajuda mas quando executo direto da uma mensagem de erro referente ao erro de ID no caso ID INVALIDO, tava pesquisando aqui sera que poderia ser um problema relativo a falta de utilização de sub-resources?

Comment: sera que faz sentido isso? Nesse caso quero atualizar o Status da ordem de servico, então preciso selecionar o servico referente a ordem, depois selecionar o cliente que requesitou o servico, o cliente possui usuario de acesso por isso preciso apontar para o id referente e o cliente tem nivel de acesso. Na minha cabeça ficaria algo assim: **PUT localhost:8080/TCC02/rest/ordens/{Ordem ID}/servico/{Servico ID}/cliente/{Cliente ID}/status =2;** Faz algum sentido? Se fizer como poderia aplicar isso, lembrando que consigo fazer atualizações em classes sem relacionamento por exemplo a classe serviço